# asn1c doesn't extract DEFAULT value of an OCTET STRING from the asn.1 module

Tags: c++, c, gsm, asn.1, der

I would like to parse SIMAlliance eUICC Profile Package ASN.1 module and encode it to DER. The `keyAccess` parameter is an `OCTET STRING` with `DEFAULT`value of `'00'H`. asn1c compiler cannot detect/extract the default value and assign it to the corresponding function produced by the compiler. It works fine if I change the `OCTET STRING` to something else like `IA5String` in the module, but the standard shouldn't be changed. Plus the value should be an octet string.

I've delved into the asn1c's code but I couldn't figure out the mechanism/procedure that it extracts and assigns the `DEAFAULT` value of an `OCTET STRING` to the functions it produces during the compilation. Any help on this would be meaning and appreciated a lot - it's a lifesaver for me.

SIMAlliance eUICC profile package ASN.1 module can be found [here](https://simalliance.org/euicc/euicc-technical-releases/) and asn1c's repository is [here](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c).

Comment: Is [asn1c's issue #366](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c/issues/366) yours?

Answer (score 1):

> The keyAccess parameter is an OCTET STRING with DEFAULT value of '00'H. asn1c compiler cannot detect/extract the default value and assign it to the corresponding function produced by the compiler. It works fine if I change the OCTET STRING to something else like IA5String in the module

This sounds like a missing feature or a bug in `asn1c`.

> I've delved into the asn1c's code but I couldn't figure out the mechanism/procedure that it extracts and assigns the DEAFAULT value of an OCTET STRING to the functions it produces during the compilation. Any help on this would be meaning and appreciated a lot - it's a lifesaver for me.

The code that produce functions like `asn_DFL_4_cmp_1` and `asn_DFL_4_set_1` is in `try_inline_default()` function in [libasn1compiler/asn1c_C.c:2329-2487](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c/blob/fdb68ce2782423ce38caf84f28441d1b0776e9ee/libasn1compiler/asn1c_C.c#L2329-L2487)

```c
static int
try_inline_default(arg_t *arg, asn1p_expr_t *expr, int out) {
    int save_target = arg->target->target;
    asn1p_expr_type_e etype = expr_get_type(arg, expr);
    int fits_long = 0;

    switch(etype) {
    case ASN_BASIC_BOOLEAN:
        fits_long = 1;
        /* Fall through */
    case ASN_BASIC_INTEGER:
    case ASN_BASIC_ENUMERATED:
```

Also there is `emit_default_string_value()` function in [libasn1compiler/asn1c_C.c:2311-232](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c/blob/fdb68ce2782423ce38caf84f28441d1b0776e9ee/libasn1compiler/asn1c_C.c#L2311-L2327)

```c
static void 
emit_default_string_value(arg_t *arg, asn1p_value_t *v) {

    OUT("static const uint8_t defv[] = ");
```

Comment: Hi @Vasil-Velichkov!

Thanks for the time you took and for your reply.

My value is `'00'H`, yet the value shown in the header file is ``/* DEFAULT '00'HH */;``. and the functions  `asn_DFL_4_cmp_1` and `asn_DFL_4_set_1` are not produced in the corresponding C file - it just says `/* No default value */`.

Would you please help me figure this out that how the code should work in the way that functions  `asn_DFL_4_cmp_1` and `asn_DFL_4_set_1` get produced for `OCTET STRING`?